# Using data fetched in one Activity in another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I get certain data like say `userName` in `Activity_1` from a web server. Then i want to use the same data in `Activity_2`

so i made this userName `Public` `Static` and used like this in `Activity_2`

```
Activity_1.userName
```

But then when i am in `Activity_2` and `press Home Button` and reopen the application 5 mins later, this `Activity_1.userName` become `Null` since that `Activity_1 data is destroyed`. and I get `NullPointerException`

How to solve this in a simple way.

I just gave an example of userName but actually its some other data which changes everyday, like say "news of the day"

Many would suggest to remove `public` `static` and send that userName as:

```
Intent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
```

But isn't this same as what i am doing. I mean even this way i will get `NullPointerException` right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be two ways to do this.

1. Always make sure that Activity1 is the starting activity in your application. I mean, if the user closes the app and restarts it again, the application should from Activity1 and thus fetch the data again. And then only go to Activity2. Also note that you can do the fetching the data from the web in Activity2 itself by using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
2. Save the data from the Activity1 in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and in Activity2 always use the SharedPreferences to read the values.

Comment: i have 2 problems, 1 each for the points you mentioned. 1. You are saying "is the user relaunches the app", but my case is "user reopens the app, by which i mean, user is in Activity_2 and clicks home button and after 5 mins tries to open the app, which opens the Activity_2 which was there when the user clicked home button", and secondly i need this data in almost all the Activities, you are right i can get this data in the Activity_2 itself, but why get the data again which i already have in Activity_1

Comment: 2. You want me to store userName in db or as a share preference, but i just gave an example of userName but actually its some other data which changes everyday, like say "news of the day".

Comment: For 2. , even if it is the news of the day, the data would be fetched by Activity1. So the data you are going to display in the Activity2 is the data already stored in Activity1. All I am saying is that as soon as you load the data from the web in Activity1, store them in the SharedPrefs and in Activity2 read from them. Now if your user reopens the app, it would still show him the old content until new data is fetched. That is how it would have worked if you were using the static variables, so I guess this should not be an issue.

Comment: Here is an idea. Display the previously stored content of the SharedPrefs in the Activity2. Now, have a mechanism to update the values by fetching from the server once again via an AsyncTask, if you feel that the data might have gone outdated. You can either use a Timer or keep a button for the user to refresh the content. And as soon as you get these new values, write them on the SharedPrefs.

Comment: eww. yeah you are right. so even if the data changes it wont reflect until i relaunch the app. reopening the app from Activity_2 will show the old content itself. Thanks a lot

Comment: Like I said in my above comment, you really don't need to relaunch the app. If you were using your static variables, you would have had to relaunch but in this you can just keep a mechanism to refresh the data if the user feels it's outdated. Hope it helps you. :)

Comment: but if you see answer by @Pork. he says just send data through intent, this data wont be destroyed, even if the Activity_1 is destroyed. If this is true, then this is simpler right?? i mean is that true??

Comment: Yeah, I saw his answer. Am not 100% sure about it actually. Truth to be said, I find it **very tedious** to send 10 or more values through intents and then again store them and pass them around. Hence, I stick to static variables and SharedPrefs.

Comment: fine. But its always recommended not to use static variable :). and i thought of sending those 10 values as 1 String and use a special char between them and then use Split() and get each string. Thanks again

Comment: That takes a lot of String operations and I am just lazy. :P Anyway, glad that you got it working. Good luck ahead.

Answer (score 2):

The intent is saved so the correct answer is to use putExtra. When your activity needs to be reinstantiated, it will be created again using the intent.

Comment: but Activity_1 is destroyed completely. Still this intent data will be available??

Answer (score 2):

you could add a action to this event and catch the event only if the action exists...

And of course you could save the data persistently - SQLite database or SharedPreferences

Answer (score 2):

As swayam suggested, i will suggest you yo go for a DB or Shared prefs, Especially Shared prefs suits best for your scenario;

You can use something like as follows:

To Put:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_READ",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        Editor prefsPrivateEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsPrivateEditor.putString("yourkey", userName);
prefsPrivateEditor.commit();
```

To Get:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        Context otherAppsContext = null;
        try {
            otherAppsContext = getApplication().createPackageContext(
                    "your.package.name", 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Email.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        sharedPreferences = otherAppsContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_READ",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

        String getusername = sharedPreferences.getString("yourkey","default_value");
```

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned this: "I just gave an example of userName but actually its some other data which changes everyday, like say "news of the day""

Comment: is it a single string or complex data?

Comment: Actually alot of Strings. but i thought of keeping them in 1 String and use a special char between them and then use Split() and get each string

Comment: then you can use it since you are storing a single string inside:) try it out if possible:)